# how can i check if my sqlflite database has data while starting the app in flutter?

Tags: sqlite, flutter, dart

I am doing a project where I have to keep an favorite icon and a selected fvrt list... Now using sqlflite .. I have done it.. when the user presses the favorite border icon it get changed to red color and the data saves in the favorite list.. when user pressses again in the same button .. the data gets delated from the list and the favorite button change to ist default color... but what i am not able to do is.. the favorite button is default false.. so even if the data is collected in the fvrt list .. all the fvrt button shows _fvrt default favorite btn when i start the app ...
i was wondering how can i check the data in the initState() , if the data already exit in database it fvrt btn will remain red..

here's a little code of the conditon that i haved used .

```
Widget _buildRow(String pair) {
    final bool alreadySaved = _saved.contains(pair);
    print("Already saved $alreadySaved");
    print(pair);
    return IconButton(
      icon: new  Icon(


       alreadySaved ? Icons.favorite : Icons.favorite_border,
        color:alreadySaved? Colors.red : Colors.white,
      ),onPressed: (){
      setState(() {
        if (alreadySaved) {
          _saved.remove(pair);
          _deleteEmployee(pair);
        } else {
          _saved.add(pair);
          _insert(pair);

        }
      });
    },
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading data from your database is an async function - it takes some time. What you can do, is to create a loading state, and show a loading indicator, until the async function finishes.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyClass extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyClassState createState() => _MyClassState();
}

class _MyClassState extends State<MyClass> {
  bool isLoading = false;
  List _saved = []; 


  @override
  void initState() {
    // Note that you cannot use `async await` in  initState
    isLoading = true;
    _readFromDataBase().then((savedStuff) {
      _saved = savedStuff; 
      isLoading = false;
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return !isLoading ?  _buildRow("myPair") : CircularProgressIndicator(); 
  }

  Widget _buildRow(String pair) {
    final bool alreadySaved = _saved.contains(pair);
    print("Already saved $alreadySaved");
    print(pair);
    return IconButton(
      icon: new  Icon(


       alreadySaved ? Icons.favorite : Icons.favorite_border,
        color:alreadySaved? Colors.red : Colors.white,
      ),onPressed: (){
      setState(() {
        if (alreadySaved) {
          _saved.remove(pair);
          _deleteEmployee(pair);
        } else {
          _saved.add(pair);
          _insert(pair);

        }
      });
    },
    );
  } 
}
```

Alternatively you can check the FutureBuilder Widget. Here is the official documentation: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html